# Confidence interval about the difference between false positive and false negative proportions

Tags: categorical-data, binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution

Consider a multinomial $2\times 2$ table $\begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{pmatrix}$ with theoretical probabilities: $$\begin{pmatrix} \theta_{11} & \theta_{12} \\  \theta_{21} & \theta_{22} \end{pmatrix}.$$

Let us call $p:=\dfrac{\theta_{12}}{\theta_{11}+\theta_{12}}$ the "false positive" proportion and $q:=\dfrac{\theta_{21}}{\theta_{21}+\theta_{22}}$ the "false negative" propotion. Note that $p$ is the proportion parameter of the binomial conditional distribution of $x_{12}$ given $x_{11}+x_{12}$ and similarly $q$ is the proportion parameter of the binomial conditional distribution of $x_{21}$ given $x_{21}+x_{22}$.

I am looking for a frequentist confidence interval about the difference $p-q$. Alternatively I am also interested in a Bayesian confidence interval as long as its confidence level is sufficiently close to its credibility level (I have checked on some examples that the Jeffreys credibility interval is a little too anti-conservatist).

Comment: I don't have this as a complete answer but I will give you my approach.  Let Ph=X12/TFp and Qh=x21/TFe where TFp=(x21+x22). Then I would try to construct the confidence interval using Ph-Qh.  I haven't even thought about how to construct a pivotal quantity out of this.  The cutoff for the confidence interval would be based on the multinomial for (x11, x12, x21, x22) keeping in mind that the multinomial has the constraint x11+x12+x21+x22=N  where N is the total sample size. I was also thinking about conditioning on the marginal totals and see how a conditional CI would look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see (forgive me if i'm wrong), $p$ and $q$ are *independent* proportions, so you're after a confidence interval for the difference between two independent proportions. A comparison of various methods for constructing such intervals was conducted by Robert Newcombe:

Newcombe RG. [Interval estimation for the difference between independent proportions: comparison of eleven methods.](http://www3.interscience.wiley.com/journal/3157/abstract) *Statistics in Medicine* 1998; 17(8):873-890.

He found the simplest method with good performance was one involving combining Wilson score intervals for the two proportions ('Method 10' in the above paper).

Newcombe wrote an Excel spreadsheet which implements his recommended formulae for this and other CIs of several estimates involving proportions, available at http://medicine.cf.ac.uk/primary-care-public-health/resources/ .

Comment: Your main point is the independence between $p$ and $q$. Rigorously speaking, that would mean: 1) $x_{12}$ is conditionally independent of $x_{21}+x_{22}$ given $(x_{11}+x_{12},x_{21}+x_{22})$; 2) $x_{21}$ is conditionally independent of $x_{11}+x_{12}$ given $(x_{11}+x_{12},x_{21}+x_{22})$; 3) $x_{12}$ and $x_{21}$ are conditionally independent given $(x_{11}+x_{12},x_{21}+x_{22})$. I'm tired, am I right ? And if I am right, is it true ?

Comment: I'm tired too, and i'm feeling more unsure than i was, so i hope a third party will confirm or deny.

Answer (score 2):

I think @onestop had the right intuition about the independence of the proportions. Below is the justification.

Let $(X_{11},X_{12},X_{21},X_{21})$ following the multinomial distribution under a probability $\Pr$ (with $\Pr(X_{11}+X_{12}+X_{21}+X_{22}=N)=1$).

We know that  $(X_{12} \mid X_{11}+X_{12}=n_1) \sim \text{Bin}\left(n_1; \frac{\theta_{12}}{\theta_{11}+\theta_{12}}\right)$ and  $(X_{21} \mid X_{21}+X_{22}=n_2) \sim \text{Bin}\left(n_2; \frac{\theta_{21}}{\theta_{21}+\theta_{22}}\right)$. We need to prove that $X_{12}$ and $X_{21}$ are independent under a suitable conditional probability.

Let $n_1$ and $n_2$ be integers such that $n_1+n_2=N$. Obviously $\Pr(X_{12}=i \mid X_{11}+X_{12}=n_1, X_{21}+X_{22}=n_2) = \Pr(X_{12}=i \mid X_{11}+X_{12}=n_1)$ and $\Pr(X_{21}=j \mid X_{11}+X_{12}=n_1, X_{21}+X_{22}=n_2) = \Pr(X_{21}=j \mid X_{21}+X_{22}=n_2)$.

Secondly, $X_{12}$ and $X_{21}$ are conditionally independent given the event $\{X_{11}+X_{12}=n_1, X_{21}+X_{22}=n_2\}$. Indeed, by elementary algebra, it is not difficult to check that the intuitive equality $$\Pr(X_{12}=i \mid X_{21}=j, X_{11}+X_{12}=n_1, X_{21}+X_{22}=n_2) = \Pr(X_{12}=i \mid X_{11}+X_{12}=n_1)$$ holds true (this is more easy if knowing in advance that $(X_{12} \mid X_{11}+X_{12}=n_1) \sim \text{Bin}\left(n_1; \frac{\theta_{12}}{\theta_{11}+\theta_{12}}\right)$).

That shows that $X_{12}$ and $X_{21}$ are independent and distributed according to $\text{Bin}\left(n_1; \frac{\theta_{12}}{\theta_{11}+\theta_{12}}\right)$ and $\text{Bin}\left(n_2; \frac{\theta_{21}}{\theta_{21}+\theta_{22}}\right)$ respectively under the conditional probability $\Pr(\cdot \mid X_{11}+X_{12}=n_1, X_{21}+X_{22}=n_2)$.

(EDIT). The Newcombe interval is available in the R package pairwiseCI. Below are some simulations showing the actual coverage of the $95\%$-confidence interval in function of $\theta_{12}$ when I fix $N=288$, $\theta_{11}=0.3$, $\theta_{22}=0.4$.

```r
    library(pairwiseCI)
    
    N <- 288
    theta11 <- 0.3
    theta22 <- 0.4
    
    nsims <- 10000
    vtheta12 <- seq(0, 1-theta11 - theta22, le=51)
    coverage <- rep(0, length(vtheta12))
    for(i in 1:length(vtheta12)){
        theta12 <- vtheta12[i]
        theta21 <-  1-(theta11+theta12+theta22)
        FPR <- theta12/(theta11+theta12)
        FNR <- theta21/(theta21+theta22) 
        diff <- FPR-FNR
        cover <- 0
        for(k in 1:nsims){
            tab <- rmultinom(1, N, c(theta11, theta12, theta21, 
                          theta22))
            bounds <- Prop.diff(x=rev(c(tab[1], tab[2])), 
                  y=c(tab[3], tab[4]), CImethod="NHS")$conf.int
            cover <- cover + ((bounds[1]< diff) & (bounds[2] > 
                        diff))
        }
        coverage[i] <- 100*cover/nsims
    }
    
    plot(vtheta12, coverage, type="l", 
        xlab="theta12", ylab="coverage (%)") 
    abline(h=95, lty="dashed")
```

[image: coverage]